# How to extract values from a Python request

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-requests

I am using a Python request to search for a specific item.

```
page = requests.get('https://utas.s2.fut.ea.com/ut/game/fifa16/transfermarket?maxb=900&start=0&type=player&maskedDefId=177604&num=16', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
print page.json
```

The code above outputs in json (see below) which I would like to extract just the the `tradeId` and print it to my terminal.

```
{u'sellerEstablished': 0, u'itemData': {u'rating': 80, u'itemType': u'player', u'resourceId': -2147306044, u'cardsubtypeid': 1, u'morale': 50, u'lifetimeAssists': 0, u'id': 242123805234, u'statsList': [{u'index': 0, u'value': 45}, {u'index': 1, u'value': 0}, {u'index': 2, u'value': 0}, {u'index': 3, u'value': 1}, {u'index': 4, u'value': 0}], u'assetId': 177604, u'teamid': 1, u'pile': 5, u'suspension': 0, u'rareflag': 1, u'playStyle': 250, u'attributeList': [{u'index': 0, u'value': 77}, {u'index': 1, u'value': 53}, {u'index': 2, u'value': 72}, {u'index': 3, u'value': 75}, {u'index': 4, u'value': 81}, {u'index': 5, u'value': 72}], u'loyaltyBonus': 1, u'timestamp': 1443853245, u'training': 0, u'nation': 45, u'assists': 0, u'formation': u'f442', u'lifetimeStats': [{u'index': 0, u'value': 45}, {u'index': 1, u'value': 0}, {u'index': 2, u'value': 0}, {u'index': 3, u'value': 1}, {u'index': 4, u'value': 1}], u'leagueId': 13, u'untradeable': False, u'discardValue': 640, u'owners': 2, u'injuryGames': 0, u'contract': 3, u'injuryType': u'none', u'lastSalePrice': 1500, u'fitness': 99, u'itemState': u'forSale', u'preferredPosition': u'LB'}, u'tradeId': 159804881070, u'confidenceValue': 100, u'sellerName': u'FIFA UT', u'expires': 1745, u'buyNowPrice': 900, u'tradeOwner': False, u'offers': 0, u'startingBid': 650, u'watched': None, u'currentBid': 700, u'tradeState': u'active', u'bidState': u'none', u'sellerId': 0}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it as a dictionary.

```
a = page.json()
print a['tradeId']
```

Comment: They are using an older `requests` version (probably in the 0.8 series packaged with Ubuntu LTS), where `.json` is still a property and not a method.

Comment: But the output the op has mentioned looks like a dictionary. So if type of page.json can be identified, we can know how to access the tradeId. I may be wrong, but worth a shot :)

Comment: Absolutely, but you changed the `page.json` reference to `page.json()`, which will likely result in an error for the OP.

Comment: receiving the following error 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Can you check what is the type of a, i.e. print type(a)

Comment: @blackmamba <type 'instancemethod'>

Comment: @Martin: Can you do a = page.json() 
Do you receive any error?

Comment: @blackmamba I don't get an error when I print page.json(). It just prints out the json

Comment: Then I am editing the answer which will work for you.

Comment: @blackmamba I am now receiving KeyError: 'tradeId'

Comment: Can you check the output of a.keys() and print it here.